# React Query returning undefined inside useMemo function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

I'm trying to add the data that I got from react-query to the useMemo hook but I still got undefined even after confirming that isLoading is done.

I'm using a custom hook for my react-query

```
const {isLoading, error, isSuccess, status, data: category } = useQueryData(
  "/v1/category", 
  "get", 
  "category"
);
```

Here is my useMemo

```
 const result = React.useMemo(() => {
  if (!isLoading && status === 'success')  {
    return category.data
  }
 }, [isLoading]) 
 console.log(result) //undefined then the data will be loaded
```

[image]

Comment: You left out the dependency array at the end of the `useMemo`. Can you show us that?

Comment: there's no need to useMemo that data because it will be referentially stable anyways between renders ...